# how to create array form field of custom Type in symfony 3?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a custom form type `AddressType`
I want to use this type inside a form as an array
I tried

```
$builder->add('addresses', CollectionType::class, [
'entry_type' => AddressType::class,]);
```

but i could not add any field in this form object, 
and when i tried

```
$builder->add('addresses', AddressType::class, []);
```

I could provide only one Address object in the form, so
how can I be able to post an array of AddressType object like this

```
"addresses": [{
    "firstName" : "firstName",
    "lastName": "lastName",
    "street": "street",
    "city": "city",
    "postcode": 123,
    "countryCode": "code"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first approach, using **CollectionType**, was a correct one,  - basically that is an array of **AddressType** fields according to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html).

When your entities and form types are correctly configured, you may manually add one or more **AddressType** fields to the collection field of your form (e.g. in controller) & then render this form field items in the twig using **for** loop.

This and a bit more difficult & advanced approaches may be found also in [symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html). I would advise you to follow the example shown there, looks a lot like your problem case.